# How Resolve Currency IDR in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, currency

How can resolve script like this ?
for example count or minus Variable A and Variable B in currency IDR 
thanks, anyone can help me ...

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-us">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<title>New Page 1</title>
</head>
<body>
<form name="form1">
<input id="harga" onkeyup="formatangka_titik()" type="text" />
<input id="diskon" onkeyup="formatangka_titik()" type="text" />
<input id="bayar" onkeyup="formatangka_titik()" type="text" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

here code javascript function :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function formatangka_titik()
{
    a = form1.harga.value;
    b = a.replace(/[^\d]/g,"");
    c = "";
    panjang = b.length;
    j = 0;
    for (i = panjang; i > 0; i--)
    {
    j = j + 1;
    if (((j % 3) == 1) && (j != 1))
      {
    c = b.substr(i-1,1) + "." + c;
    } else {
    c = b.substr(i-1,1) + c;
    }
    }
    form1.harga.value = c;
</script>
```

Comment: Please elaborate on what you expect to be happening and what specifically is not working as expected in your code.

Comment: <form method="POST" name="form1">
 <p>Currency IDR</p>
 <p><sub><input type="text" name="harga" size="20">
 <input type="text" name="diskon" size="20">
 <input type="text" name="bayar" size="20"></sub></p>
 <p>For Example : 1.250 + 1000 = 2.250</p>
 <p>&nbsp;</p>
</form>

Comment: Consolidate your code, formulate a specific question, and give desired results.

Comment: No you'll have to edit your post to make the question less vague and to only show the relevant code

Comment: @m_callens: I wanted to addition or subtraction in the form of currency IDR in the script above . for example 2,000 + 1,500 = 2.0001.500 , should if in total to 3,500 . so use the above script does not run , can help me ?

Comment: @thanksd: can u help me ?

Comment: @Havika I've made fiddle with the code you've provided. I'm not sure though what you're trying to accomplish. Can you tell me what the three fields are supposed to do? https://jsfiddle.net/fs3e0axc/1/

Comment: ya,, the point is for example 1.500+1.000=2.500 with comma, and 1'st field for 1.500 and 2nd fields for variable 1.000 and the last count variable 1'st field+ 2nd fields

Comment: doesn't work @ https://jsfiddle.net/fs3e0axc/1/

Comment: anyone can help me ?

Comment: @thanksd the https://jsfiddle.net/3da367Lk/3/ has modified, but still doesn't work, if i try at w3school its work, but the result no to do

Comment: @Havika is there a link for the w3school thing you're talking about?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_variables change the editor with script above or at jsfiddle.net/3da367Lk/3

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you are adding two strings together, which will concatenate the strings instead of add the numeric values.

Example adding string types:

```
var a = '1';
var b = '2';
console.log(a + b); // prints '12' to the console
```

Example adding int types:

```
var a = 1;
var b = 2;
console.log(a + b); // prints '3' to the console
```

JavaScript is loosely typed, so it's not always immediately apparent what a variable's type is.

You can do a few things to change a string-type variable to an int. 
Here are a couple common ways:

```
var stringNum = '123';
var intNum1 = parseInt(stringNum, 10);
var intNum2 = +stringNum;
```

**Specifically, your code would need to look something like this:**

```js
function formatangka_titik() {
  var a = form1.harga.value.replace(/[^\d]/g, "");
  var b = form1.diskon.value.replace(/[^\d]/g, "");

  var a = +a; // converts 'a' from a string to an int
  var b = +b; // converts 'b' from a string to an int

  form1.harga.value = formatNum(a);
  form1.diskon.value = formatNum(b);
  form1.bayar.value = formatNum(+a + b);
}

function formatNum(rawNum) {
  rawNum = "" + rawNum; // converts the given number back to a string
  var retNum = "";
  var j = 0;
  for (var i = rawNum.length; i > 0; i--) {
    j++;
    if (((j % 3) == 1) && (j != 1))
      retNum = rawNum.substr(i - 1, 1) + "." + retNum;
    else
      retNum = rawNum.substr(i - 1, 1) + retNum;
  }
  return retNum;
}
```

```html
<form name="form1">
  <input id="harga" onkeyup="formatangka_titik()" type="text" />
  <input id="diskon" onkeyup="formatangka_titik()" type="text" />
  <input id="bayar" onkeyup="formatangka_titik()" type="text" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

In above example how we can calculate percentage for IDR currency.